# typescript - Pass around optional options object with default values

Tags: typescript, function, parameters

In typescript, I want to be able to pass no arguments, an options object with some values set, or an options object with all values set. In the first two cases, the default values for the option keys that have not been passed should be used. We can do this already with:

```
const f = ({ a = 1, b = 'b' } = {}) => {
};

f() // a = 1, b = 'b'
f({}) // a = 1, b = 'b'
f({ a: 2 }) // a = 2, b = 'b'
f({ a: 2, b = 'bb' }) // a = 2, b = 'bb'
```

but what if we want to pass the options object around - is there any way of not duplicating the different keys in the options?

```
const f = ({ a = 1, b = 'b' } = {}) => {
  g({ a, b }) // Is there any way of avoiding duplicating the list of option keys?
};
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have "as patterns" for object destructuring (see [here](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/destructuring-as-patterns) for discussion) where you can *both* destructure an object properties into named variables *and* maintain a name for the object you've destructured.  Any solution here is going to involve mentioning `a` and `b` multiple times somewhere, as far as I can tell.  Let me know if I should write that up as an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement JavaScript options object parameter pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32654633/implement-javascript-options-object-parameter-pattern)